# I'm having a problem with seo and htaccess, crawlers check twice my site

Tags: html, .htaccess, seo

I'm trying to optimize my SEO, I'm trying some websites like sitechecker dot pro

[image: Both pages listed]

I still don't know why it reads my site as two sites, the domain and `index.html`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
```

I have SSL also, but I still don't know what's the issue.

by the way, my canonical URL is:

```
 <!-- Canonical URL -->
 <link rel="canonical" href="/index.html" />
```

Hope I can get some help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Make to add **robots.txt** for your site

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <!-- Canonical URL -->
> <link rel="canonical" href="/index.html" />
> ```

Maybe you have just updated this, but that isn't what your pages state:

> ```
> <!-- Canonical URL -->
> <link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/" />
> ```

...which would indeed be the preferred URL (ie. without `index.html`). It is also the URL you are linking to *mostly* on your page.

However, you are still linking to `index.html` from your logo. This needs to be corrected to simply `href="/"`.

You need to make sure you are linking to only one of these URLs throughout your site.

Once you have corrected all your internal links then you can implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to correct this for search engines and any users that might be following a bookmark or 3rd party link.

For example, to remove `index.html` from the URL, you could add the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file (immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive):

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
```

But this must only be implemented once all internal links have been corrected.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid caching issues.

The preceding `RewriteCond` directive is to ensure we don't get a redirect loop (since mod_dir issues an internal subrequest for `index.html`).